# Does the set have to be pretty explicitly given as an element of the topology?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So I've been trying to grasp the concept of what is and isn't a topological space recently, and it has brought me upon some questions that I'm on the fence as to whether they are topological spaces or not. Suppose for example we have:
$$
\tau = \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2: \text{U is an open disc or } \emptyset \} 
$$
This is extremely vague to me. If we chose $(x,y)$ tending towards infinity, we would get very close to the set $X$ being included in $\tau$, but the fact that it's never completely within makes me want to say that it's not a topological space. I think it will also fail under the union/intersection of a number of open discs, but the main issue is in understanding whether it violates the rule that the set itself and the empty set must be elements of the topological space.

Comment: Are you assuming that everyone learns those "rules" in the same order?

Comment: What is “vague” about the definition of $\tau$? Don't you understand which subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ belong to $\tau$ and which ones don't?

Comment: @AnotherUser Good point, I've edited it to reflect that

Comment: Let $B(x,r) = \{ y : d(x,y) < r\}$ denote the ball with radius $r$ centered at $x$.  Is $B((0,1),1) \cup B((0,-1),1)$ an element of $\tau$?

Comment: Since $\Bbb R^2$ is not an open disk, then indeed $\Bbb R^2\notin\tau$.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of an open disk containing $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Is this because of the fact that even as x and y tend to infinity, the fact that we can add 1 to both and have a number outside the disk enough of a reason to say $\mathbb{R}^2 \notin \tau$?

Comment: Your example $\tau$ is evidently not a topology because $\mathbb R^2$ is not an open disk. Note that every open disk is a bounded set.

Comment: Please stop writing about $x$ and $y$ tending to infinity. That makes no sense. An open disk is a set of the form$$\{p\in\Bbb R^2\mid\|p-q\|<r\},$$for some $q\in\Bbb R^2$ and some $r>0$. But this open disk is not $\Bbb R^2$ since, for instance $q+(r,0)$ does not belong to it.

Comment: Frankly, this is not an exercise in topology, it is an exercise in set theory. And from a set theoretical standpoint, there is nothing vague whatsoever about the set $\tau$, its set-builder formula is perfectly clear, assuming that you know the definition of an open disc. Your job on this problem is to work through it like a set theorist would: Does this set $\tau$ satisfy the axioms of a topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of two open disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open disk if and only if one is contained in the other. Thus your set is not a topology. It's a *subbase* for a topology, though, because the intersection of two open disks is a union of open disks.

The set on which the topology is defined is the union of the subbase, that is, $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Some textbooks (Kelley, for instance) define a topology as any family of sets that's closed under arbitrary unions and binary (or finite) intersections.

If $\tau$ is such a family, then
$$
X=\bigcup\tau=\{x:\text{$x\in U$, for some $U\in\tau$}\}
$$
is the largest set in the family (it belongs to $\tau$ because of closure under arbitrary unions) and it is the set the topology is defined on.